# git log to show commits different between two branches, including common ancestor

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff, git-log

When working on feature branches (e.g., `feature`) created off of our main (e.g., `master`) branch, I use the following git command to view a list of commits that have been added to the `feature` branch that are not on the `master` branch:

```
git log --oneline master..HEAD
```

This outputs a nice short summary of the commits on `feature` that aren't on `master` (note, this command is run after checking out the `feature` branch):

```
$ git log --oneline master..HEAD
1ca070a (HEAD -> feature) foo the bar
03a1047 baz the wuz
c9e8279 fop the sip
6ee6d6f up the ante
5812200 bop the binky
```

The problem is, it doesn't show the common ancestor commit on the `master` branch. What I would like is for the command to include one more line, that's the common ancestor commit, like this:

```
1ca070a (HEAD -> feature) foo the bar
03a1047 baz the wuz
c9e8279 fop the sip
6ee6d6f up the ante
5812200 bop the binky
fb37d68 (master) fuzzy the wuzzy
```

I would expect that replacing `master` with `master~1` would include one commit prior to the common ancestor, and therefore include the common ancestor,

```
git log --oneline master~1..HEAD
```

but whether I specify `master` or `master~1`, the log summary is always the same.

```
$ git log --oneline master~1..HEAD
1ca070a (HEAD -> feature) foo the bar
03a1047 baz the wuz
c9e8279 fop the sip
6ee6d6f up the ante
5812200 bop the binky
```

**My question is, how can I include the common ancestor commit in the log summary?** Note that the common ancestor is not necessarily the tip of the `master` branch.

Comment: The `~1` probably should have done what you wanted. (That it didn't, means you've added commits to `master` too.) Try `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` and observe the graph to see which commit `master~1` actually is, to see why `master~1..HEAD` failed here. Meanwhile, consider the `--boundary` flag, but in my experience this selects too many commits.

Comment: @torek you're absolutely right - the ancestor commit only shows up using `master~1` if the common ancestor commit is the tip of `master`. (If I rebase the `feature` branch onto the tip of `master`, then using `master~1` shows the ancestor commit as expected.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that this kind of `--boundary` includes *too many* commits quite often, but:

```
git log --boundary --right-only --oneline master...HEAD
```

should get you close-ish.  Add `--graph` (and for completeness `--decorate`, though you obviously have `log.decorate` set) to get something even more useful.  Leave out the `--right-only` to get the most useful output.  Given the `--right-only`, you can simplify this to `--boundary master..HEAD`, but read on to see why I suggest not using `--right-only`, but using `--graph`.

What this does is a bit complicated:

- The three dot syntax `master...HEAD` requests a *symmetric difference*.  That is, we get all commits that are reachable from `master` but not from `HEAD` from the left side of the three dots, and all commits reachable from `HEAD` but not `master` on the right side.
- The `--right-only` option, if specified, eliminates the left-side commits.
- The `--boundary` option adds back, to the set of commits to be visited by the graph walk, those commits that were specifically chosen as *not* to be shown via the symmetric difference algorithm.

Consider this graph, drawn with parent commits to the left and children to the right (rather than parents below and children above as `git log --graph` does):

```
          C--D--E   <-- master
         /
...--A--B
         \
          F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The uppercase letters here stand in for commit hash IDs.  Commits `E` back to `C` are reachable from `master`, and commits `H` back through `F` are reachable from `HEAD` (which is attached to the name `feature`).  Commit `B` is the merge base of these two sets of commits.

Here, `master...feature` selects commits `C-D-E` on the left and `F-G-H` on the right.  (Note that reversing the names—`feature...master`—selects the same commits, but now `C-D-E` would be on the right.)  So adding `--right-only` to this set gets you *almost* what you want: commits through `HEAD`, excluding commits reachable from `master`.  That's the *same* output you'd get from the simpler `master..feature`.

Now, if we add `--boundary`, Git will include commit `B` as well.  That is, both `git log --boundary master..feature` or `git log --boundary --right-only master...feature` will show commits `B-F-G-H` (in the other order).

With `--decorate`, when `git log` shows commit `H`, it will add the `HEAD -> feature` decoration.  But commit `B` has no branch name, so it will not be decorated.  It will be hard to tell that commit `B` belongs to *both* branches.

Without `--right-only` and with `--boundary` and `--graph`, Git will show commits `C-D-E` on master and `F-G-H` on feature, with `E` and `H` decorated, and will include boundary commit `B`.  The resulting graph will show pretty clearly that `B` is the shared merge-base commit.

When the graph gets complicated, `--boundary` adds back *too many* commits.  The extra commits will still be displayed reasonably clearly—as clearly as these things get when there are as many graph lines as `git log --graph` introduces, anyway.  You can add `--simplify-by-decoration` to help eliminate a lot of the visual clutter: the resulting graph is probably readable, and will let you identify the shared commit.

Answer (score 4):

There does not seem to be a `git` command that allows you to do exactly this. The `master..HEAD` syntax means:

> commits on `HEAD` but **not** on `master`

The following statements are equivalent:

```
git log --oneline master..HEAD
git log --oneline HEAD --not master
```

so especially if you are dealing with merge commits, it is complicated to explain to git what part of the history you want to exclude.

## bash workaround

You can however tell `git log` how many commits he should show, so with a little bash magic the following command should do what you want:

```
git log --oneline -$(( $(git rev-list --count HEAD ^master) + 1))
```

to explain:

- `$(git rev-list --count HEAD ^master)` counts the number of commits on your current branch since master
- `$(( num + 1 ))` increases that num by one.
- and then we run `git log --oneline -123` (with 123 the number of commits on your branch + 1)